# MSO Excel - Add padding to the fill color of the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to add some padding to the fill color of a cell?
Now if you set a fill color on a cell, the cell is always completely filled.

(I use Excel 2016 preview, but it looks just the same as 2013 :))

Comment: If I understand you correctly, why not set a border for the cell?

Comment: That's an great idea. I've set a white border so it looks like padding. But can i set a custom border width?

Comment: Only certain [presets](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lCe5b.png) are available (that screenshot's from an older version but I don't think it has changed much if at all in Excel 2016). [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AmxVF.png) shows the thickest and thinnest borders available.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the cell and left click on Format Cells.., then left click on Fill tab, there you can choose background color (also no color), pattern color, pattern style, and special effects.